# Bluetooth: Can receive files, but no "Send Files" option

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I'm unable to send files via Bluetooth since I can't find the "Send Files" option anywhere.

See screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Use the 'Set up new device' menu and set up a new device. Then you can send files to it.

Comment: @Parto You see that device entry `DESKTOP-SJ6PJDS` on the left  of the Bluetooth Settings window? It got there via "Set up new device". I want to send files to that device but I can't see how I can do that.

Comment: Try and click on it...